# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when .length is zero

Tags: java, arrays

I got a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and I think it is because when nums.length gives me a zero (because there is nothing inserted in the parameter) the attribute I gave to the variable (-----.length -1------) will make it -1 when it gives me zero.

How should I make it not do this knowing that if I leave it .length without a -1 there will be an out of bounds exception on the other side of the array?

```
    public boolean sameFirstLast(int[] nums) {
      int lengthOfArray = nums.length - 1;
      int thisIsHowLong = nums.length;

      if (nums[0] == nums[lengthOfArray ] && thisIsHowLong > 0){ 
         return true;
      }


  return false;
}

//always remember to return false in the end becuse if the top dosnt run then 
//there will be no boolean returned and the method is not void so it has to return a //boolean

//ALWAYS REMEMBER TO SET nums.length - 1
//the .length method always starts from 1 and threfore will give you an extra space //that it will check for but we wont have anything in that space and then the compiler //will go to that space and will fond nothing to test with and gove an ERROR out of //bounds exeption because it is looking out of the array.
```

Comment: Please use `nums.length() - 1` inside the array index, e.g. `nums[nums.length() -1]`

Comment: change the order of your both conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition should look like
    `if(thisIsHowLong > 0 && nums[0] == nums[lengthOfArray ] )`

Now if your first condition is false, second will never be checked.
And you want same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to interchange the conditions.

```
  if (thisIsHowLong > 0 && nums[0] == nums[lengthOfArray ]){ // This will prevent the exception.
```